# Is it possible to cut an image from another image in iOS?

Tags: ios, image-processing, graphics

Can anyone tell me if the following is implementable and if yes point me in right direction. Let's say we have a picture on the screen in our iOS app. Then i select an area on this picture drawing a shape with my finger and then the selected area gets cut off and becomes a separate image i can work with. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

fast answer: yes it is possible

look at
https://github.com/iridia/UIImage-Additions

- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds;  in UIImage+Resize.h

this method is what you are looking for to cut your image

your job is to calculate the bounds from your screen selection